# NSExtension activation rule not working

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-extension, ios-extensions

I am building an iOS8 action extension and I am using **NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount** set to **1**

The problem is, the extension does not show up in Safari share menu unless I go to the extension menu and turn my extension on (using the switch) and then after I use my extension, it again becomes invisible and I have to go to the extension menu and turn it on again and this keeps happening over and over again.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug that only affects development builds installed via Safari. There's no fix or workaround, but it doesn't affect app store releases.